# Python API for simple OpenCV image proc, called with JSON inputs

Tags: python, api, opencv

## Background

I've got OpenCV & Python installed on a Docker container which is on a http server to process images and serve them. The user interface is through the web; user inputs an image and some values; the values are collected through a form and the values and image paths (hashed input and output paths) are sent through JSON to a bash script which runs the Python code. There are two Python scripts; one which does the JSON input processing (`cspaceIO.py`), and the main processing module (`cspaceFilter.py`) which is only called by the first script.

---

## Questions

1. Is there anything here that screams "bad idea" with the flow of this approach?
2. Do I need to worry about anything security-wise that my `_sanitize()` function doesn't help with?
3. How do the python scripts look on their own?

---

## I/O script `cspaceIO.py`

```
import argparse  # command line inputs
import cspaceFilter  # running the algo
import cv2  # for checking the image
import json  # for i/o


"""Validator functions"""


def _sanitize(filename):

    sanitized = "".join(
        [c for c in filename
         if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c in ['.', '_', '-', '/']]).rstrip()

    return sanitized


def _checkimg(imgPath):

    img = cv2.imread(imgPath)

    if img is None:
        invalidmsg = ("%s is an invalid image filename, "
                      "did not load image." % imgPath)
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(invalidmsg)

    return img


def _checkcspace(cspaceLabel):

    validLabels = ['BGR', 'HSV', 'HLS', 'Lab',
                   'Luv', 'YCrCb', 'XYZ', 'Grayscale']

    if cspaceLabel not in validLabels:

        invalidmsg = ("{0} is an invalid colorspace, must be one of: "
                      "{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, or {8}."
                      ).format(cspaceLabel, *validLabels)

        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(invalidmsg)


"""Command line parsing"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """To be ran from command line

    Usage example:
        python3 cspaceIO.py '{
            "paths":
            {
                "srcPath":"input/test.png",
                "maskPath":"output/test.png",
                "maskedPath":"output/test2.png"
            },
            "cspaceLabel":"BGR",
            "sliderPos":[127,255,127,255,127,255]
        }'
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Color threshold an image in any colorspace \
                     and save it to a file.')

    parser.add_argument('jsonIn', help='JSON containing paths \
        (dict {imgPath (str), maskPath (str), maskedPath (str)}), \
        cspaceLabel (str), and sliderPos (6-long int list[])')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # grab inputs from json
    jsonIn = json.loads(args.jsonIn)
    paths = jsonIn['paths']
    srcPath = paths['srcPath']
    maskPath = paths['maskPath']
    maskedPath = paths['maskedPath']
    cspaceLabel = jsonIn['cspaceLabel']
    sliderPos = jsonIn['sliderPos']

    # check inputs
    _checkcspace(cspaceLabel)
    srcPath = _sanitize(srcPath)
    maskPath = _sanitize(maskPath)
    maskedPath = _sanitize(maskedPath)
    img = _checkimg(srcPath)

    # run the colorspace filter script
    mask, masked_img = cspaceFilter.main(img, cspaceLabel, sliderPos)

    # write the output image
    cv2.imwrite(maskPath, mask)
    cv2.imwrite(maskedPath, masked_img)
```

---

## Image processing module `cspaceFilter.py`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


"""Helper functions"""


def _cspaceSwitch(img, cspaceLabel):
    """Coverts the colorspace of img from BGR to cspaceLabel

    Keyword arguments:
        img -- the image to convert
        cspaceLabel -- the colorspace to convert to

    Returns:
        img -- img with the converted colorspace
    """
    if cspaceLabel == 'BGR':
        return img

    convert_code = {
        'HSV': cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV,
        'HLS': cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS,
        'Lab': cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab,
        'Luv': cv2.COLOR_BGR2Luv,
        'YCrCb': cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb,
        'XYZ': cv2.COLOR_BGR2XYZ,
        'Grayscale': cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY}

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, convert_code[cspaceLabel])

    return img


def _cspaceBounds(cspaceLabel, slider_pos):
    """Calculates the lower and upper bounds for thresholding a
    colorspace based on the thresholding slider positions.

    Keyword arguments:
        cspaceLabel -- the colorspace to find bounds of; see keys in main()
        slider_pos -- positions of the thresholding trackbars; length 6 list

    Returns:
        lowerb -- list containing the lower bounds for each channel threshold
        upperb -- list containing the upper bounds for each channel threshold
    """

    if cspaceLabel is 'Grayscale':
        lowerb, upperb = slider_pos[0], slider_pos[1]
    else:
        lowerb = np.array([slider_pos[0], slider_pos[2], slider_pos[4]])
        upperb = np.array([slider_pos[1], slider_pos[3], slider_pos[5]])

    return lowerb, upperb


def _cspaceRange(img, cspaceLabel, lowerb, upperb):
    """Thresholds img in cspaceLabel with lowerb and upperb

    Keyword arguments:
        img -- the image to be thresholded
        cspaceLabel -- the colorspace to threshold in

    Returns:
        mask -- a binary image that has been thresholded
    """
    img = _cspaceSwitch(img, cspaceLabel)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lowerb, upperb)

    return mask


def _applyMask(img, mask):
    """Applies a mask to an image

    Keyword arguments:
        img -- the image to be masked
        mask -- the mask (non-zero values are included, zero values excluded)

    Returns:
        masked_img -- the input img with mask applied
    """

    masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    return masked_img


"""Main public function"""


def main(img, cspaceLabel, slider_pos):
    """Computes the colorspace thresholded image based on
    slider positions and selected colorspace.

    Inputs:
        img -- input image
        cspaceLabel -- colorspace to filter the image in
        slider_pos -- positions of the six sliders (6-long int list)

    returns
        mask -- mask created from thresholding the image
        masked_img -- masked image
    """
    lowerb, upperb = _cspaceBounds(cspaceLabel, slider_pos)
    mask = _cspaceRange(img, cspaceLabel, lowerb, upperb)
    masked_img = _applyMask(img, mask)

    return mask, masked_img
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sanitized = "".join(
    [c for c in filename
     if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c in ['.', '_', '-', '/']]).rstrip()
```

Just a small improvement - as strings are sequences, you may change it to

```
sanitized = "".join(
    [c for c in filename
         if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c in "._-/"])
```

( `.rstrip()` is superfluous as you don't allow whitespaces.)

Comment: Great catch there, pushing straight to development with that one.